# React Redux how to add data to object's array

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

My user structure is:

user = {
email: 'email',
flashcards: []
}

And i would like to add data into user's flashcards array (using redux)

My user-reducer

```
import { UserActionTypes } from './user.types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  currentUser: null,
};

// GETS STATES OBJ AND RECIVES AN ACTION
const userReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UserActionTypes.SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state, 
        currentUser: action.payload, 
      };
    case UserActionTypes.ADD_FLASHCARD:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentUser: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default userReducer;
```

user-actions

```
export const addFlashCard = user => ({
  type: UserActionTypes.ADD_FLASHCARD,
  payload: user.flashcards,
});
```

And when i'm doing so my payload is undefined.

Could you give me some hints?

Comment: how are you dispatching your action `addFlashCard` . can you please add that code as well ?

Comment: Console.log(user) in action function to see the data is correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently overwriting `currentUser` with the value of `user.flashcards` from the redux action. To add new flashcards, the `ADD_FLASHCARD` branch of your reducer should look more like this:

```
case UserActionTypes.ADD_FLASHCARD:
  return {
    ...state,
    currentUser: {
      ...state.currentUser,
      flashcards: [
        ...state.currentUser.flashcards,
        ...action.payload
      ]
    }
  };
```

Comment: That was the point. I didn't know how to manage state in reducer..